# How to get errors from python requests when host is unreachable?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

im trying to make small watchdog script for pinging container with nginx.
this is my code:

```
import requests
import time
url = 'http://localhost:1234/'
response = ''

    
def checkloop (url, response):
    
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        
        

    except requests.ConnectionError:
        
        print("Can't connect to the site, sorry")
    else:
        response.status_code == 200
    
        print("OK", response.status_code)
    
while response == '':
    checkloop (url, response)
    time.sleep(5)
```

But i cant get error when host is in down state. script breaking. i always getting this error:

```
"requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=1234): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10332e4c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))"
```

how i can get in print() 403 or 404 or another error when host is different when httpget 200 code? is it possible?

or maybe you can advise to me already working watchdog for python or small manual how to do that?

Comment: You can check [`Response.status_code`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.status_code) manually or use [`Response.raise_for_status()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) which will raise [an exception](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions).

Comment: Your code as shown prints "Can't connect to the site, sorry".  It is catching the exception.

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP 2xx/3x/4xx/5xx answer from the server requires to be able to HTTP-connect to the server. If you can't connect at the network level at all (host unreachable), you can't connect at the HTTP level (see [the OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)).

Instead of making your `checkloop` function update the global variable `response`, you could use your function to tell you if the server is reachable. Example :

```py
import requests
import time
url = 'http://localhost:1234/'

def can_connect_to(url) -> bool:  # `bool` is a type hint for the return type of the function
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("Can't connect to the site, try again later")
        return False  # can NOT connect
    else:
        # do whatever you want
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("OK 200")
            return True  # can connect
        else:
            print("strange ...", response.status_code)
            # return True or False ?

while not can_connect_to(url):
    time.sleep(5)
```

If you need the `response` content, you can use Python's Thruthy/False value for that, which looks like what you posted :

```py
import requests
import time
url = 'http://localhost:1234/'

def fetch(url) -> str:  # we expect a string to be returned (any length)
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("Can't connect to the site, try again later")
        return ""  # can NOT connect, we don't have any content for now
    elif response.status_code == 200:
        print("OK 200")
        return response.text  # can connect
    else:
        print("strange ...", response.status_code)
        return response.text  # may be truthy or falsy ...

while not response_text := fetch(url):  # call fetch, put the result into `response_text`, and check if its truthy or falsy
    time.sleep(5)

# at this point, `not response_text` is False, which means that `response_text` is truthy, which for a string means it is non-empty
print(response_text)
```